# Add react native module inside android kotlin app

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin

I am trying to add a new React native module to an existing android application. I already was able to make the android app open the react native activity following the guide that React Native provides.

Now I am trying to open the main activity from my android app when i press a button in the react native code. Does anyone know how to achieve that? Google is not helping me finding a solution for this. If someone can point me in the right direction.